# Emploi du mot "aergonique"

Tags: usage, science

The term *aergonic* comes from the Greek roots *a* meaning “not” and *ergon* meaning “work”, that is, it means “no work has occurred.” It is the analog of the word adiabatic (adiabatique), meaning no heat transfer has occurred (this being from the greek word adiabatos= who that is impassable).

Considering that the root *ergon* exists in the word *[exergonique](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C3%A9action_exergonique)* can we use in French the term *aergonique* ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Aergonique* doesn't exist in French.

The expected form is ***[an](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/an-#fr)ergonique***, but it is extremely rare, only two hits by now, soon three when this reply will be scanned by the search engine robots.